# Modeless userform causes crash

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I learned recently that changing the **`ShowModal`** property of a **`userform`** allows the user to still access the worksheet, so I changed mine from True to False.

After doing that, when I click OK on the form, I get a **`"Application-defined or object-defined error"`**.

***UPDATED***

```
sub CallForm()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With myForm
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
        .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
        .Show
    End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

end sub
```

And my userforms have code like this:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()

    [myCell] = CDbl(TextBox1)
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

and that error occurs where I try to dump the textbox inputs into the worksheet.  While stepping through the code, the **`worksheet_change()`** triggers even though I turned **`EnableEvents`** Off prior.

Anyone know why the error would occur?

Comment: You should show more code. Hard to tell with so little context.

Comment: Where's the code that turns events off and loads the form?

Comment: I've included this gist of what I'm working with above.

I tried doing a very simple test case in a separate workbook and that worked OK with no errors, so now I'm even more confused.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. use For index = 1 to 500  Debug.Print Error$(index) Next index to find error? Also is text box one not a double value? Also clearly the OK_Click sub is what is firing the worksheet change events so thats obviously related.

Comment: TextBox1 is always a double (number) when I click OK.  I can even still see the number in the textbox when the code crashes.

Events shouldn't be triggering again until after the form is closed since I disabled them prior to Showing the userform.  Unless ShowModal changes this which is kind of what I was asking.